# Set Maxlength for Laravel Form::number(

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I have this code

```
{{ Form::number('amount', (isset($logged_in_user->paymentConfirmation->amount) ? floor($logged_in_user->paymentConfirmation->amount) : null), ['class' => 'form-control', 'maxlength' => '13','step' => '1']) }}
```

How to limit length to 13 digit length?

Comment: If you're generating an INPUT of type NUMBER, just replace 'maxlength' => '13' with 'max' => '9999999999999''

Answer (score 0):

Laravel Collective Forms renders `Form::number` as `<input type="number">` element. So you need to use [`max`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_max.asp) here and it's value must be a maximum allowed integer:

```
{!! Form::number('amount', (isset($logged_in_user->paymentConfirmation->amount) ? floor($logged_in_user->paymentConfirmation->amount) : null), ['class' => 'form-control', 'max' => '9999999999999', 'step' => '1']) !!}
```

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_max.asp